# Как из приложения разместить сообщение на личной страничке (на стене) Facebook?

Tags: java, android, facebook

Как добавить в своё приложение возможность размещения пользователем сообщения с изображением на его стене в Facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно вот [так](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/publish-to-feed/)

как подключить сдк написано вот [тут](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/)

Если хочешь что нибудь попроще, то вот [еще](http://androidthings.blogspot.ru/2011/10/adding-share-button-to-your-android.html#.UP_awaXw9z8). Здесь написано как создать кнопку по которой вылезет список всех приложений установленных на телефоне, через которые можно шарить

Comment: Роман Захаров, вот последний способ, в принципе подходит. Только непонятен момент как добавить изображение в сообщение?   И можно ли сделать так чтобы по нажатию кнопки "отправить" был не список доступных вариантов, а только facebook?

Comment: по поводу как добавить картинку например вот http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661875/how-to-use-share-image-using-sharing-intent-to-share-images-in-android

Comment: Роман, не очень точно сформулировала задачу : надо чтобы и текст и картинка (из drawable) в сообщении были. По отдельности без проблем добавляется или то или другое.

Answer (score 1):

Ну например:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585043/android-how-to-post-the-message-with-the-image-post-on-facebook

Про картинку тут:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292508/post-message-with-photo-in-facebook-with-android-and-got-error-an-unknown-error

Ну и еще вот:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726429/post-message-to-facebook-wall-from-android-fb-sdk-always-error

И еще даже:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168145/android-post-picture-to-facebook-wall

А вообще, используя официальный SDK от Facebook:)
Была такая же задача, только еще и для вк и твиттера.

Конечно умение найти на английском ответ в гугле убрало бы большинство вопросов тут. Качайте скилл:)

Comment: DroidAlex, с английским это точно подмечено )).